# How to access view in unique ListView position?

Tags: android

I have a list view I'm adapting `list_item.xml` to. `list_item.xml` is just a layout with a `CheckBox`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on one of these check boxes, I want the other checkboxes to uncheck. So In my adapter in the `getView` method I add the `CheckBox` to the `CheckboxManager` singelton class.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View list_item = convertView;//View Recycling

    if (list_item == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        list_item = vi.inflate(R.layout.database_item, null);
    }

    DatabaseItem databaseItem = getItem(position);

    if (databaseItem != null) {

        TextView textView = (TextView) list_item.findViewById(R.id.database_name);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) list_item.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setText(databaseItem.getTitle());
        }

        if (checkBox != null) {
            CheckboxManager cbm = CheckboxManager.getInstanceOf(activity);
            cbm.addCheckbox(checkBox, databaseItem.getQuery());
        }

    }

    return list_item;
}
```

In my `CheckboxManager` singleton class I accumulate the `CheckBox` views into an `ArrayList`. I set a click listener to the check-boxes and un-check them when one of them is checked by iterating over the array list.

The problem is that my array list size is always one! Since I am adapting five instances of `list_item.xml` I expected there to be five unique `CheckBox` views but apparently there is only one as my `ArrayList` is only ever size 1 (maybe because of view recycling?).

How can I access all the check boxes and uncheck them all?

**edit**

```
public class CheckboxManager {

    private ArrayList<CheckBox> cbs = new ArrayList<>();
    private static CheckboxManager singleton = null;
    private static Activity activity = null;

    private CheckboxManager(Activity activity){ this.activity = activity;}

    // This is the only class method; the rest are instance methods.
    public static CheckboxManager getInstanceOf(Activity activity){

        if(null == singleton) return new CheckboxManager(activity);
        return singleton;
    }

    public void addCheckbox(CheckBox cb, String query){

        addClickListener(cb, query);
        cbs.add(cb);
    }

    private void addClickListener(final CheckBox cb, final String query){

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

               @Override
               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                   // A box has been checked
                   if(true == isChecked) {
                       uncheckOtherBoxes(cb);
                       Movies.swapCursor(getCursor(query), activity);
                   }
               }
           }
        );
    }

    private void uncheckOtherBoxes(CheckBox cb){
        int idx = cbs.indexOf(cb);
        Log.v("TAG","Size of list is "+cbs.size());
        for(int i=0;i<cbs.size();i++){
            if(idx != i){
                cb.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private Cursor getCursor(String query){
        SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseHelper.getInstanceOf(activity).getDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your singleton isn't formed properly.

This is wrong. You can see it just returns a new instance everytime, because it never stores it the first time.

```
public static CheckboxManager getInstanceOf(Activity activity){

    if(null == singleton) return new CheckboxManager(activity);
    return singleton;
}
```

It should be...

```
public static CheckboxManager getInstanceOf(Activity activity){

    if(null == singleton) 
       singletone = new CheckboxManager(activity);
    return singleton;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure why I should move that line into my `onCreate` method. As per your second point, I simply assumed that a new instance of `CheckBox` view was instantiated by the adapter and inserted into my `ArrayList` of check-boxes via the manager.

Comment: Thought it might work better as a field just in case it was creating a new instance.

Comment: I get what you're saying. The manager is a singleton class so there is only every one instance of it and the array list with the check boxes in it is static. Included the class in the edit.

Comment: Looks like it was creating a new instance every time. Thanks for adding the CheckboxManager code so that I could find the issue.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it was, although I don't see how lol. I just threw the singleton design pattern out the window and just used a class with all static variables and static methods. Problem solved!